# Imageview doesnt work on my test phone and also on emulator

Tags: java, android, imageview

Tried to display simple imageon phone. And i get error.

Here is the xml code for imageview

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="400px"
    android:layout_height="400px"
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="172dp"
    android:src="@drawable/img1"
    android:background="#ffffff" />
```

My pic is in drawable folder. I saw few posts about same problem but couldnt solve it. Tried t reduce width and height from wrap contect to 400px and tried to put white background but i still get the same error. When i try to open application with emulator or my phone i get his error message: **Unfortunately, DajanaGallery has stopped.**

Comment: How do you know the ImageView is the problem? Please read this post, then show the logcat. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this

Comment: What error you get?

Comment: add logcat here

Answer (score 0):

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="400dp"
    android:layout_height="400dp"
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="172dp"
    android:background="@drawable/img1"/>
```